# Passing data BACK ! to a screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Let us say we have 2 pages `Page 1 and Page 2`.

`Page 1` has one Button and a Text widget.
When a user **taps** on the button, the button **navigates** to page 2.

On the other hand, `page 2` has just a textField at the center of the page.
When the user **types** something on the textField, I expect the **Text** widget in `page 1` to change.

I'm trying to change the value **without re-navigating back to the `first page`**. In fact I'm trying to **pop the context** and get the new or changed value.

In other languages, they use global variables which makes **that same variable usable everywhere**, is it possible to solve such in dart and flutter?

Comment: Yes you can use Global variable.

Comment: Navigator.pop can be used to do this: [check out this link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data "returning data to a screen")

Answer (score 0):

i have found the same issue. i found the solution by using state management.

i have found solution with Getx State management.

solution:-

step 1:- define controller class

```html
class Demo extends GetxController {
  RxString xyz = "".obs;
}
```

// on page 1 define Demo class like this

```html
 Demo demo = Get.put(Demo());

    Obx((){
Text("${demo.xyx.value}"),
})
```

// on page 2 define demo class like we do.

```html
TextFormField(
  onChanged: (text) {
                demo.xyz.value = text;
              },
)
```

it will change your string in page 1 when u change value of textfield;

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer.
you need to make good use of InheritedWidget.

`InheritedWidget` is like a tree that holds many leafs or in my case `Widgets`.

At the top level of the main widget or the `Page 1`. Their should be another widget that `extends InheritedWidget`, you can name it Pages for example.

```
class Pages extends InheritedWidget {
..

}
```

It doesn't really matter how many widgets it will have after it e.g. Page3, Page4, Page5 etc.

That **`same`** variable will used and updates whenever a change was made and any of the other widgets e.g. Page4, Page3, Page5, Page1 etc.

you can read more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html).

or you can use a package name `injectable`, you can read more [here](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable).